# Layered Architecture in NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, architecture, domain-driven-design

If we're talking about layered architecture. Should the event dispatching be inside the `MessageService.create` function or is it common to have it directly in the handler? The `EventDispatcher` is responsible for sending push notifications, emails etc. via a queue.

Some people argue that firing (domain) events should be inside your service layer. But domain events should always contain information like the authenticated user. So if I would fire events inside my `MessageService`, I would always need to pass the authenticated user, which I think, is a bit overkill.

The downside of this is that the handler is now coupled to HTTP, so when I want to create a batch of messages via a node script or something, the `message.created` will not be triggered, because it is not part of the service logic.

```
module.exports = async function createMessageHandler(request, reply) {
  request.log(['message', 'create']);

  const message = await MessageService.create(request.payload);

  EventDispatcher.emit('message.created', {
    message: message,
    actor: request.auth.credentials,
  });

  return reply({ data: message });
}
```

Comment: `domain events should always contain information like the authenticated user` - why? Do you mean in general or in your context?

Answer (score 0):

Unless I am mistaken an `actor` is most likely not a concept of your domain and therefore doesn't really belong in domain events. Generic information collected for auditing purpose fits better as event **meta-data**.

Pay attention to your Ubiquitous Language. For instance, `PostCreated { author }` or `CaseReviewed { reviewer }` rather than relying a generic concept such as `actor`.

Event meta-data is usually recorded on the storage envelope of your domain event which gets dealt with in the infrastructure rather than the domain.